# Cpu Metric in JobHistory logs processed with Rumen

Tags: json, hadoop, metrics

I gathered stats of my jobs in a Hadoop Cluster.  I took the JobHistory logs and process them with Rumen. In the json file, for each task attemp, there are a field named "cpuUsages".

Example:

```
"cpuUsages" : [ 6028, 3967, 3597, 3354, 3225, 3454, 3589, 4316, 42632, 102, 103, 103 ]
```

I need to know the unit of measurement of this numbers. Some official or academic reference for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rumen](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-rumen/Rumen.html) extracts metrics from MR job history server. So the metrics is same to the one in MR job history server.

You can see [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/HistoryServerRest.html) that MR job history server provides CPU usage in **MILLI SECONDS**. So the unit of measurement can be Wall CPU usage time in milli seconds.